# Refresh all on all open worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have master sheet in which data from various "options" sheets pulled now I want to refresh all "options" sheets to get refresh on specific interval for that I have following vba code in master sheet

```
Public interval As Double
Sub Dosomething()
Dim xSh As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each xSh In Worksheets
    xSh.Select
    Call macro_timer
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub macro_timer()
 interval = Now + TimeValue("00:03:00")
 Application.OnTime interval, "my_macro"
 End Sub


Sub my_macro()
 For Each wb In Application.Workbooks: wb.RefreshAll: Next wb
 Call macro_timer
 End Sub
```

However code is not working as I wanted somewhere I am lacking, don't know where. pls help.thx

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

1. Loop all open workbooks
2. Refresh

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopOpenWorkbook()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

        wb.RefreshAll

    Next wb

End Sub
```